# Bootstrap works when imported by CDNS but not when imported by Node modules

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code

Basically, I am trying to learn and test out bootstrap. I've noticed I can get it working by importing the files exactly as the template on their website shows for cdns. But when I install boostrap, poppper, and jquery through node, and import the exact same files. It doesnt work. I have attached two screenshots showing what I mean.
[Bootstrap collapse working when I import using the CDNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2Hq.png)

[Bootstrap collapse not working when I import using the node modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9154.png)

EDIT: here is my file system
[files system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ds5j.png)

Comment: Is `./node_modules/..` the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

So everything was working the whole time, the syntax had changed from boostrap versions and the reason I had it working with that cdn was because it was actually an old version of it. Once I replaced my syntax with the version 5 syntax, everything worked from importing with the node modules.